# how to use OUTPUT pane in vscode when working on virtualenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created the `virtualenv` for my project. I want my output to be in **OUTPUT** pane but whenever I am using `virtualenv` I can only get output in terminal only I am using python.

Is there any way I can get output in "**OUTPUT**" pane ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because VS Code uses the built-in powershell of the computer, choosing to run the code will output the result in the terminal window by default.

[image]

If you want to display the output in the **OUTPUT** window, you can install the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. After installing this extension, the play button that originally ran the code will have an additional **Run Code** option.

[image]

select this option to run the code, and the result will be output in the **OUTPUT** window.

[image]

If you want to get clean output in the **OUTPUT** window (without any extra lines), you can add the following configuration in `settings.json`:

```json
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```